# Writing JSON preserving double backslashes

Tags: json, python-3.x, psycopg2

I want to store python data structures as json on a Postgresql database.

The `json.dumps()` works well and I get a properly formed JSON, as in:

```py
>>> import json
>>> j = { 'table': '"public"."client"' }
>>> json.dumps(j)
'{"table": "\\"public\\".\\"client\\""}'
```

If I do `print(json.dumps(j))`, only one backslash is printed, since it is used by Python as an escape character, as in:

```py
>>> import json
>>> j = { 'table': '"public"."client"' }
>>> json.dumps(j)
'{"table": "\\"public\\".\\"client\\""}'
>>> print(json.dumps(j))
{"table": "\"public\".\"client\""}
```

#### The problem

When I try to store this json on Postgresql with `psycopg2`, the [backslashes should not be stripped](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#values-containing-backslashes-and-like), I think.

```py
import psycopg2
import json

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("service=geotuga")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    j = { 'table': '"public"."client"' }
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users.logger(subject,detail) VALUES (%s, %s);", ('json',json.dumps(j) ))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

On the database, the json string is stored as: `{"table": "\"public\".\"client\""}`. The double backslashes are gone.

**How can I store the JSON properly created by `json.dumps` with `psycopg2` without loosing the double backslashes?**

Note: The json stored on the database is no longer valid. If I try to parse it with Javascript, for example, it fails:

```
> x = '{"table": "\"public\".\"client\""}'
'{"table": ""public"."client""}'
> JSON.parse(x)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 12
```

Comment: I don't think the backslashes are being stripped out. I think it is only the way they are represented depending on how you observe them. Have you tried doing a select to the database and parsing it from there, instead of trying to parse the string manually?

Comment: Good point @luigibertaco. I think you are right! Can you transform this comment into a answer? I've tested by computing the string length and by using the json support in Postgresql. Postgresql is able to parse it, so it is properly stored.

Answer (score 0):

As *luigibertaco* pointed out, the problem was how I observed the data in the database. **The double backslashes are being properly written to the database, using `psycopg2`**.

If I do:

```sql
# select detail from users.logger where subject = 'json' limit 1;
               detail               
------------------------------------
 {"table": "\"public\".\"client\""}
(1 row)
```

The output shows just one slash.

But if I use the `quote_literal` Postgresql function, I get the raw data:

```sql
# select quote_literal(detail) from users.logger  where subject = 'json' limit 1;
               quote_literal               
-------------------------------------------
 E'{"table": "\\"public\\".\\"client\\""}'
(1 row)
```

#### Postgresql was able to parse the string

Another check I've made, was testing the json parsing on Postgresql side. It works, so the string is properly encoded.

```sql
# select detail::json->'table' from users.logger where subject = 'json' limit 1;
        ?column?         
-------------------------
 "\"public\".\"client\""
(1 row)
```